# How do I connect clojure core.logic to a database?

Tags: clojure, clojure-core.logic

I have been enjoying Clojure core.logic but I have run into a wall.  I need to be able to have it use a database, either SQL or not, rather than an in memory data structure.  As I have looked around I see mention of a `to-stream` function but no solid examples of its use.

Does anyone have a good example of using core.logic with a database?

Comment: There's an example of connecting it to Dataomic in the core.logic documentation -- did you take a look at that?  https://github.com/clojure/core.logic/wiki/Extending-core.logic-%28Datomic-example%29

Comment: I have seen that and I think the problem is I don't use Datomic so I do not quite grok what the example in the Custom Data Sources actually does.  I almost have it but I don't see how I would, for example, run a query based on the data it is trying to unify against.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As someone has already suggested in the comments look at the Datomic example in the [core.logic repository](https://github.com/clojure/core.logic/blob/master/src/main/clojure/clojure/core/logic/datomic.clj#L78). Based on the example there you could imagine writing something like this:

```
(defn query [db query-string out]
  (fn [a]
    (to-stream
      (map (fn [result] (unify a out result))
        (db-query db query-string)))))
```

All core.logic goals just return closures which take a substitution map `a` (you can of course call it whatever you like). Essentially you need to map over the results and unify them with `out` in `a`.

Then you could imagine writing a core.logic program like the following:

```
(run* [q]
  (fresh [row]
    (query some-db "... some query string ..." row)
    (some-other-goal row q)))
```

Comment: Thanks, that does make it clearer.  Does it make sense to build the query string based on the results of other goals?

Comment: That's possible but of course a lot more work depending on what you want to support.